# Send email in R that reads email addresses from .csv file

Tags: r

I am sending an email via R using hard coded email addresses. I am trying to capture the email address directly from the .csv file source. To tried the following:

```
MailAdd <- read.csv(‘Mailfile.csv’, header=FALSE))

MailAdd <- unlist(MailAdd)

MailAdd <- as.vector(MailAdd)
```

The MailAdd output I get is “Neel_check@hotmail.com”. When I plug this vector in the mailR to section, it doesn’t give any error but I don’t get any email.

However when I hard code the email address ‘Neel_check@hotmail.com’ in mailR to section, I get the emails.

The only difference I see is the vector has double quotes whereas hardcoding has single quote. I thought in R it shouldn’t matter.

Any suggestions on this. Thanks

Comment: Please share some reproducible data - what does `dput(head(MailAdd))` show after running this code? Also please show where you `MailAdd` with the command to send the email.

Comment: You can also make a toy data set that has the same format as "Mailfile.csv" with fictional emails.

Comment: Hi Greg, the dput(head(MailAdd)) returns - “Neel_check@hotmail.com. The mail command is as follows: toList <- (MailAdd) mailR:: send.mail (from = “check@hotmail.com”, to = toList, subject = emailSubject, etc etc…

Comment: So if I change the toList vector as toList = c(‘Neel_check@hotmail.com’) and keep everything else same, I get the email.

Comment: Hi Gregor, I don’t know why it worked but I just replaced the toList using your statement and I got the email. toList <- dput(head(MailAdd). If you have any reason on why this worked, please share your thoughts. Thanks